# Keep newlines in output of cut

Tags: bash, text-processing, cut

Let's imagine we have a file:

```
foo bar
foo1 bar1
```

I want to cut every second word in every line, so I want file to look like this:

```
foo
foo1
```

I am trying to use `cut -d ' ' -f -1` but what I get is:

```
foo foo1
```

How can i preserve line endings in the file?

Comment: do you mean `cut -d' ' -f1`?

Comment: could you post how you're using that? cut leaves the line endings intact, i'm guessing you're using the output of cut in a way that's replacing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

file contents

```
john@caffe:~$ cat listing.txt
foo bar baz
foo1 bar1 baz1
```

getting the first column only

```
john@caffe:~$ cut -d' ' -f1 listing.txt
foo
foo1
```

getting the first and third column, this time from stdin through a pipe

```
john@caffe:~$ cat listing.txt | cut -d' ' -f1,3
foo baz
foo1 baz1
```

EDIT: I think I know what you're doing wrong

```
john@caffe:~$ foo=$(cut -d " " -f -1 listing.txt)
john@caffe:~$ echo $foo
foo foo1
john@caffe:~$ echo "$foo"
foo
foo1
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add quotes when tested it with echo.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `--output-delimiter`  option of cut, i.e. `cut -f 1 -d ' ' --output-delimiter='\n'` in your case

Comment: This has nothing to do with the output delimiter, if you bother reading the accepted answer and the comments...